# notifyall() not the last statement

Tags: java, concurrency, monitors

Assume I have a Read/Write monitor implementation in Java.

Several Readers OR One Writer can access the database at any one time (not both)

```
class RWmonitor{
   private int readers = 0;
   private boolean writing = false;

   public synchronized void StartRead(){ ..}
   public synchronized void EndRead(){ 
      notifyAll();
      readers--;
   }

   public synchronized void StartWrite(){ ..}
   public synchronized void EndWrite(){
      notifyAll();
      writing = false;
   }
}
```

Now, does it matter if `notifyAll()` is not the last statement in the synchronized method?

Assume:

1) `EndRead()` executes

2) `notifyAll()` notifies all waiting threads

3) Then  it reduces the reader count.

When it executes `notifyAll()`, will it just be more costly since the woken up threads would be waiting for the lock on RWmonitor to be released? (assuming the thread that has the lock on RWmonitor is still at `readers--;`)

Answer (score 4):

It does not matter if it is the last statement.

To quote the [javadoc for notifyAll()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#notifyAll%28%29):

> *The awakened threads will not be able to proceed until the current thread relinquishes the lock on this object.*

Comment: will there be any difference in efficency? or would be considered negligable?

Comment: @ali - in theory it's probably more efficient to exit the synchronized block as soon as possible after notifying (i.e. notify should be the last action).

Answer (score 3):

No, it doesn't matter. The lock will still be held until the end of the `synchronized` block, and no threads will be able to `wait` on the lock in the intervening time. In fact it is slightly advantageous to have the notify first in that an exception may stop the update but not the notify.

Comment: ahh.. thats interesting to think that the exception may stop the update. Thanks!

Comment: but, if the update doesn't happen, then you likely don't need the notify in the first place.

Comment: @jtahlborn If there is an exception after the notify but before the update, then threads wake up but got around their while-loop, which is safe. (Though you might lose the release.)

Comment: @jtahlborn Ah but the other way around, you get the update but no notify, so the other threads are stuck there even though they should proceed. Though obviously it makes little difference with simple operations like this.

Comment: if an exception occurred during the update, then likely the update did not occur (at least not completely).

Comment: @jtahlborn It may or may not have completed. With an API as in the question where you are trying to match a start with an end call (always a bad idea), then you're probably in trouble either way. In more normal situations, with notify first you have either total success or total [safe] failure. With notify after you may have partial failure.

Comment: i don't understand why in one way or the other a partial failure is "safe" or "unsafe".   notify with a partial update could be just as unsafe as a partial update with no notify.  i you allow an exception to leave your system in an inconsistent state, you're stuck either way.